# Unable to compile all the patterns within a loop

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've written a script in python in combination with `re` module to scrape some content from few block of texts. My defined pattern can locate and fetch them successfully If I try individually.

However, my question is how can i get them in a single shot using those patterns in a loop? Most importantly all the fields are not available in all block of texts.

I tried (all the patterns below are working ones):

```
import re

content="""
Name: Larry King
Telephone: 514 353-4119 
Website: http://www.lexor.biz 

Name: Allen Smith
Telephone: 819 986-3429 
Website: http://aefournier.com 
Email: aefournier@videotron.ca 

Name: Paul adams
Telephone: 1-819-477-6656 
Email: info@lexor.biz 
"""
pattern = re.compile(r"Name:\s+(.*)")
# pattern = re.compile(r"Telephone:\s+(.*)")
# pattern = re.compile(r"Email:\s+(.*)")
# pattern = re.compile(r"Website:\s+(.*)")
for item in pattern.finditer(content):
    print(item.group(1))
```

Output I'm expecting to have for the first container (the email is missing in first block so the blank field should be filled in with `N/A`):

```
Larry King 514 353-4119 http://www.lexor.biz N/A

and so on--
```

Comment: Do it without using regex, read line by line and use `startswith()`.

Comment: Do the values always come in the word Name, Telephone, Website, Email, but with some of the last three optional?

Comment: Yes, they always come in the word name @abarnert.

Comment: They are within messy chunk of texts so `startswith()` won't be of much help @Casimir et Hippolyte . Moreover, they are not necessarily in the first position of a line.

Comment: Try [`dict(re.findall(r'(Name|Telephone|Website|Email):\s*(.*\S)', content))`](https://ideone.com/0MloCn).

Comment: @asmitu: it isn't a problem, you only have to trim lines before processing them. But if you absolutely want to use a regex, feel free to choose the first regex answer that seems to work. This way you avoid to provide an effort to build a simple algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your entries always come in the same order—name, telephone, website, email—but with some of the later ones optional, then you *can* do this with a regex. But it's probably not a great idea.

We can just concatenate the four patterns, with an appropriate whitespace pattern between them (I used `\n`, which works for your example as posted, but I'm not sure if it's the right one), and marking the later three optional by sticking them in a non-capturing group and appending a `?`:

```
Name:\s+(.*)\n(?:Telephone:\s+(.*)\n)?(?:Website:\s+(.*)\n)?(?:Email:\s+(.*)\n)?
```

You can see it [in action at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SU1TeD/1).

Notice that, e.g., the last match has no group 3, only groups 1, 2, and 4.

(It might be a little nicer to give the groups `?P<names>` so you can refer to them by name.)

---

But it would be much easier to solve this by just treating it as a sequence of blank-line-separated chunks, each of which is in Header: Value format. You don't even need a regex for that; it's just trivial looping over an iterable of strings.

Or, even more simply, use `itertools.groupby` to break it into chunks for you. A non-empty line is truthy, an empty line is falsey, so just group by truthiness:

```
lines = content.splitlines()

for nonempty, group in itertools.groupby(lines, bool):
    if nonempty:
        print('New Entry')
        for line in group:
           header, value = line.split(':', 1)
           print(header.strip(), value.strip())
```

Or, assuming you want to actually gather these entries into some kind of structure, like a dict of dicts keyed by name:

```
def parse(lines):
    for nonempty, group in itertools.groupby(lines, bool):
        if nonempty:
            pairs = (line.split(':', 1) for line in group)
            yield {header.strip(): value.strip() for header, value in pairs}

entries = {entry['Name']: entry for entry in parse(content.splitlines())}
```

Comment: I like your solutions with itertools. However, I must replace 'bool' with 'lambda lin: bool(lin.strip())' because I got lines with only white spaces in them when I copy the 'content' string.

Comment: @kantal Glad you got it working. Wrapping your head around `groupby` can be hard, but once you do (and it sounds like you have) it makes a lot of problems easier.